# Add "_" before all SMTP addresses in Exchange

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0

I'm looking script that help me to add "_" before all SMTP addresses in Exchange.

Let's say we have a user John Doe. John has 3 different SMTP addresses:

john.doe@contoso.com

jdoe@domain.com,

john@contoso.com

I'd like to change disable all features in Exchange (like OWA, ActiveSync and so on), hide his account in GAL and set all his addresses to:

_john.doe@contoso.com

_jdoe@domain.com,

_john@contoso.com

I can do it for primary SMTP but I can't for rest of them :(

For Now I have try such solution:

```
Set-Mailbox $sam -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -DomainController $dmc
Set-CasMailbox $sam -OWAEnabled $false -ActiveSyncEnabled $false -MAPIEnabled $false -PopEnabled $false -ImapEnabled $false -DomainController $dmc
mbx = Get-Mailbox $sam -DomainController $dmc | select -expand EmailAddresses | %{$_.SmtpAddress}

        foreach ($M in $mbx)
        {
           [string]$email += "'smtp:_"+$M+"',"
        }
```

but it doesn't works for me. I'm quite fresh in PS so could you please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what's the problem/error message? Are you using exchange cmdlets, ad module or something else?

Comment: SO is not a resource for you to post "I need a script to do X". It's expected that you have already tried something and gotten stuck on one specific portion of it.

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie and I forgot add my script, now post is correct.

Comment: What is the error message or what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

1. The main problem is that you're generating a list of the new addresses, but you're not modifying the mailbox objects. Just running a **foreach** loop against results queried from a mailbox isn't going to modify that object. You need to use **Set-Mailbox** to actually set the new addresses:

   ```powershell
   Set-Mailbox -EmailAddresses <new_addresses>
   ```
2. The way you're creating the string, it will have a trailing comma. If you want to create a comma-separated string from strings generated by a loop, do it this way:

   ```powershell
   $email = $(foreach ($m in $mbx) {
       "'smtp:_" + $m + "'"
   }) -join ','
   ```

   The loop returns an array of the strings generated by each iteration, and the `-join ','` joins them into a comma-separated string.
3. That said, you actually *don't* want to join them into a comma-separated string, because the **-EmailAddresses** parameter of **Set-Mailbox** takes an array argument. So, you just want to use the return value of the loop as the argument.
4. Adding the `smtp:` prefix is unnecessary because that's the default.
5. On the other hand, if you're only modifying SMTP addresses, you *do* want to use **Where-Object** to filter the contents of the **EmailAddresses** property for SMTP addresses:

   ```powershell
   ?{$_.Prefix.ToString() -eq 'smtp'}
   ```

Putting it all together:

```powershell
foreach ($mbx in (Get-Mailbox <whatever>)) {
  $modified_addresses = $mbx.EmailAddresses `
  | ?{$_.Prefix.ToString() -eq 'smtp'} `
  | select -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses `
  | %{"_$_"}
  Set-Mailbox $mbx -EmailAddresses $modified_addresses
}
```